# to test dynamically TCP connection test for the backend servers

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

I have a requirement to test the TCP connection of the backend servers dynamically.

Is it possible to use dp:url-open to the backend server without passing any message in an xsl ?

Thanks & Regards,
Sreevathsa A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to test the backend connectivity of the server using dp:url-open by adding ?wsdl in the and of each backend URL.

Comment: And remember to allow GET in Front-Side-Handler of the service responding.